# How to deal with "Coefficients: not defined because of singularities" in regression

Tags: r, dataframe, regression

I have a following dataframe and I need to regress "entries17" on variables stated in the regression below. Urad_2, urad_3, urad_4 are dummy variables, all other variables are numeric.

```
Office <- c(seq(1,4,1))
row1 <- c("260","2","9","71","5","7","47","19","8","36","8","17","28","8","10","38","6","8","25","15","5","14","10","10","489","177","157","154","67","17","1","2","3","4","5","6","15.48","13.26","9.11","1","0","0","0")
row2 <- c("189","30","129","149","75","77","90","50","63","143","41","38","89","67","79","115","74","58","82","86","144","170","147","52","1074","1163","1096","1056","1143","898","1","2","3","4","5","6","4.99","4.81","4.11","0","1","0","0")
row3 <- c("72","91","119","115","81","83","108","99","57","94","104","38","115","46","47","114","90","68","89","84","78","125","84","61","1061","1001","741","936","913","655","1","2","3","4","5","6","7.74","6.19","4.52","0","0","1","0")  
row4 <- c("120","130","86","132","60","66","170","169","100","194","98","56","104","130","83","177","128","96","138","108","114","214","144","151","1381","1587","1562","1431","2057","1062","1","2","3","4","5","6","7.15","5.69","4.43","0","0","0","1")
D = rbind(row1,row2,row3,row4)
D = as.data.frame(cbind(Office,D))
colnames(D)[2:44] <- c("Jan14","Feb14","Mar14","Apr14","May14","Jun14","Jul14","Aug14","Sep14","Oct14","Nov14","Dec14",
                        "Jan15","Feb15","Mar15","Apr15","May15","Jun15","Jul15","Aug15","Sep15","Oct15","Nov15","Dec15",
                       "entries14","entries15","entries16","entries17","entries18","entries19","Year2014","Year2015",
                       "Year2016","Year2017","Year2018","Year2019","UR_region_2018","UR_region_2019","UR_region_2020",
                       "urad_1","urad_2","urad_3","urad_4")
```

When I run the regression, I get an error "Coefficients: not defined because of singularities". I checked the correlation. In some cases variables are highly correlated but I need to get the coefficients for further prediction.
Any suggestion please? Thank you.

```
model = dynlm(entries17  ~ Jan14 + Feb14 + Mar14 + Apr14 + May14 + Jun14 + Jul14 + Aug14 + Sep14 + Oct14 + Nov14 + Dec14 + Jan15 + Feb15 + Mar15 + Apr15 + May15 + Jun15 + Jul15 + Aug15 + Sep15 + Oct15 + Nov15 + Dec15 + UR_region_2018 + entries16 + urad_2+urad_3+urad_4, data =D[complete.cases(D),])
summary(model)

Time series regression with "zoo" data:
Start = 1, End = 4

Call:
dynlm(formula = entries17 ~ Jan14 + Feb14 + Mar14 + Apr14 + May14 + 
    Jun14 + Jul14 + Aug14 + Sep14 + Oct14 + Nov14 + Dec14 + Jan15 + 
    Feb15 + Mar15 + Apr15 + May15 + Jun15 + Jul15 + Aug15 + Sep15 + 
    Oct15 + Nov15 + Dec15 + UR_region_2018 + entries16 + urad_2 + 
    urad_3 + urad_4, data = D[complete.cases(D), ])
Residuals:
ALL 4 residuals are 0: no residual degrees of freedom!

Coefficients: (77 not defined because of singularities)
                   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)            1431        NaN     NaN      NaN
Jan14189               -375        NaN     NaN      NaN
Jan14260              -1277        NaN     NaN      NaN
Jan1472                -495        NaN     NaN      NaN
Feb142                   NA         NA      NA       NA
Feb1430                  NA         NA      NA       NA
Feb1491                  NA         NA      NA       NA
Mar14129                 NA         NA      NA       NA
Mar1486                  NA         NA      NA       NA
Mar149                   NA         NA      NA       NA
Apr14132                 NA         NA      NA       NA
Apr14149                 NA         NA      NA       NA
Apr1471                  NA         NA      NA       NA
May1460                  NA         NA      NA       NA
May1475                  NA         NA      NA       NA
May1481                  NA         NA      NA       NA
Jun147                   NA         NA      NA       NA
Jun1477                  NA         NA      NA       NA
Jun1483                  NA         NA      NA       NA
Jul14170                 NA         NA      NA       NA
Jul1447                  NA         NA      NA       NA
Jul1490                  NA         NA      NA       NA
Aug1419                  NA         NA      NA       NA
Aug1450                  NA         NA      NA       NA
Aug1499                  NA         NA      NA       NA
Sep1457                  NA         NA      NA       NA
Sep1463                  NA         NA      NA       NA
Sep148                   NA         NA      NA       NA
Oct14194                 NA         NA      NA       NA
Oct1436                  NA         NA      NA       NA
Oct1494                  NA         NA      NA       NA
Nov1441                  NA         NA      NA       NA
Nov148                   NA         NA      NA       NA
Nov1498                  NA         NA      NA       NA
Dec1438                  NA         NA      NA       NA
Dec1456                  NA         NA      NA       NA
Jan15115                 NA         NA      NA       NA
Jan1528                  NA         NA      NA       NA
Jan1589                  NA         NA      NA       NA
Feb1546                  NA         NA      NA       NA
Feb1567                  NA         NA      NA       NA
Feb158                   NA         NA      NA       NA
Mar1547                  NA         NA      NA       NA
Mar1579                  NA         NA      NA       NA
Mar1583                  NA         NA      NA       NA
Apr15115                 NA         NA      NA       NA
Apr15177                 NA         NA      NA       NA
Apr1538                  NA         NA      NA       NA
May156                   NA         NA      NA       NA
May1574                  NA         NA      NA       NA
May1590                  NA         NA      NA       NA
Jun1568                  NA         NA      NA       NA
Jun158                   NA         NA      NA       NA
Jun1596                  NA         NA      NA       NA
Jul1525                  NA         NA      NA       NA
Jul1582                  NA         NA      NA       NA
Jul1589                  NA         NA      NA       NA
Aug1515                  NA         NA      NA       NA
Aug1584                  NA         NA      NA       NA
Aug1586                  NA         NA      NA       NA
Sep15144                 NA         NA      NA       NA
Sep155                   NA         NA      NA       NA
Sep1578                  NA         NA      NA       NA
Oct1514                  NA         NA      NA       NA
Oct15170                 NA         NA      NA       NA
Oct15214                 NA         NA      NA       NA
Nov15144                 NA         NA      NA       NA
Nov15147                 NA         NA      NA       NA
Nov1584                  NA         NA      NA       NA
Dec15151                 NA         NA      NA       NA
Dec1552                  NA         NA      NA       NA
Dec1561                  NA         NA      NA       NA
UR_region_20184.99       NA         NA      NA       NA
UR_region_20187.15       NA         NA      NA       NA
UR_region_20187.74       NA         NA      NA       NA
entries161562            NA         NA      NA       NA
entries16157             NA         NA      NA       NA
entries16741             NA         NA      NA       NA
urad_21                  NA         NA      NA       NA
urad_31                  NA         NA      NA       NA
urad_41                  NA         NA      NA       NA

Residual standard error: NaN on 0 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:      1, Adjusted R-squared:    NaN 
F-statistic:   NaN on 3 and 0 DF,  p-value: NA
```

Comment: You are trying to predict the four data points in `entries17` with way too many variables. Are you sure that this model is what you need? It's virtually impossible to fit this complicated a model with this little data.

Comment: Yes, it is a complicated model. I am trying to replicate this model using a different sample. I was thinking of modifying it to following, using "office" instead of those 3 urad dummies (represent office) `model = dynlm(entries17  ~ Jan14 + Feb14 + Mar14 + Apr14 + May14 + Jun14 + Jul14 + Aug14 + Sep14 + Oct14 +  Nov14 + Dec14 + Jan15 + Feb15 + Mar15 + Apr15 + May15 + Jun15 + Jul15 + Aug15 + Sep15 + Oct15 + 
 Nov15 + Dec15 + UR_region_2018 + entries16 + Office, data =D[complete.cases(D),])` but again I get NA estimates.

Comment: With this little data, you can't estimate the effects of these many predictors on an outcome.  Also, if you want to look into how something changes over time, I wouldn't dummy-code in a bunch of dates into the regression.